# How to count KLOC in a Java project (including front-end technologies)?

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker, metrics, lines-of-code

I would like to know the total KLOC of my projects including their front-end technologies (ex. freemarker). We are using IntelliJ IDE and Jacoco for metrics collection of Java (only) files. The standard technology stack is pretty much as follows:

1. Java, Spring, JSP, Freemarker templates, iBatis (queries in XML), Hibernate
2. Java, Groovy & Grails (gsp on the front end)

How would you come about counting total KLOC of the whole stack on each type of project?

Comment: What does it mean that you want to measure also LOC from "their front-end technologies"?

Comment: it means that all KLOC tools I am aware of (IntelliJ plugins) and Jacoco will only give me total lines of code of Java files. I also want to count code in JSPs, Freemarker templates and ideally also GSP (groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Try [ohcount](https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount). This will generate a nice report for a lot of different languages, with comment and whitespace split out.

Comment: Could you please add more details on how to use it? There's 0 documentation or instruction on the repo.